# Resolution and Significant Figures handling

Tags: math, sensors, significant-digits

I am struggling to understand which is the correct way to display a measurement done by a certain sensor after some unit conversions.

Imagine I have a sensor with resolution `R = 0.1` that provides a measured value as a `float`, with arbitrary number of decimals.

Knowing the sensor's resolution I can truncate the measured value before displaying it, in order not to give the idea of more precision than what there actually is - i.e.:

```
measuredValue = 13.275456
R = 0.1

displayedValue = 13.3
```

Now suppose I want to display the measured value in another unit (let's assume that the unit conversion consists of multiplying the measured value by the constant `2.3441212`). I know that in order not to have rounding errors, I should apply all the resolution corrections at the end, just before displaying the final value. Also, according to the [Significant Figures Rules](https://www.nku.edu/%7Eintsci/sci110/worksheets/rules_for_significant_figures.html) for multiplication

> The LEAST number of significant figures in any number of the problem determines the number of significant figures in the answer

```
measuredValue = 13.275456
R = 0.1

newUnitValue = 13.275456 * 2.3441212 = 31.1192778

measuredValue_real_significant_figures = 3 

displayedValue = 31.1
```

Now let's make `R = 0.5`. Without unit conversion we have:

```
measuredValue = 13.275456
R = 0.5

displayedValue = 13.5
```

Things don't look clear to me when the unit conversion is involved. Does the process change somehow in comparison to the one for `R = 0.1`? How is the resolution `R = 0.5` reflected on the unit converted displayed value?

Comment: `trueValue = measuredValue + epsilon`, where `-R <= epsilon <= R`. `newUnitTrueValue = (measuredValue + epsilon) * 2.3441212 = newUnitValue + newEpsilon` where `newUnitValue = 13.275456 * 2.3441212 = 31.1192778`, and `-R * 2.3441212 <= newEpsilon <= R * 2.3441212`.

Comment: I think Stef's answer is right, but it might be clearer just to say that R is scaled by the same factor as the quantity. If R = 0.5 before, then R = 0.5 x (scale factor) afterwards. It might help make it clearer to attach units to R and then convert those units too. E.g. nnn meters plus or minus R meters = nnn x 3.28 feet plus or minus R x 3.28 feet.